# Appium Android automation: how to reinstall app while keep the plist file

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium

I try to automate tests for a native android app with Appium. The feature I want to test is that certain user settings, for example, favorite search result, of the app can retain after updating to a newer version of the app. I have two version of the app and manually tested that this feature works. But when I automate the test, all the settings are cleared/reset.

My automation is done in two steps. First, in one session, install the old version, and set the favorite settings; second, start a new session, install the new version.

First step works just fine. In my second step

- If I set `full reset` to my capability before starting new session, the app is reinstalled with new version but all the settings are cleared.
- If I set `no reset` to my capability before starting new session, then I found the app is NOT reinstalled with new version at all.

How should I set the appium server flag so that in my second step, I can get my new version installed while still keeping the settings? I am guessing this has something to do with plist file of the app?

Here is my code.
settingOldVersion.java

```
package RR.upgradeTest;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import RR.utility.RRhelper;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;

public class settingOldVersion{

public static AndroidDriver DRIVER;
public static String APK_file = "oldversion.apk";

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {

        File appDir = new File("src");
        File app = new File(appDir, APK_file);

        DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "5.0.1");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("\n\n******************************************************");
        System.out.println("Installation and startup app "+APK_file);

        //Android Driver
        DRIVER=new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        System.out.println("Driver obtained");

        Thread.sleep(2000);

    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        DRIVER.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void settingFavorite() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("setting favorite");

        //Add search result into favorite
        ....

        //Take a screenshot of the favorite page
        ....

        String image_path=".//result//UpgradeTest/OldVersion//";
        String name="FavoriteSetting"+APK_file;
        RRhelper.takeScreenshot(DRIVER, name, image_path);
    }
}
```

Here is my code for checking new version: verifyNewVersion.java

```
package RR.upgradeTest;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;


import RR.utility.RRhelper;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;

public class varifyNewVersion{

public static AndroidDriver DRIVER;
public static String APK_file = "newversion.apk";

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {

        File appDir = new File("src");
        File app = new File(appDir, APK_file);

        DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "5.0.1");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
//      cap.setCapability("fullReset", true);
//      cap.setCapability("noReset", false);
        System.out.println("\n\n******************************************************");
        System.out.println("Installation and startup app "+app.getAbsolutePath());


        //Android Driver
        DRIVER=new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        System.out.println("Driver obtained");
        Thread.sleep(2000);

    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        DRIVER.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void checkingFavorite() throws Exception
    {

        //Come to Favorite page 
        Assert.assertTrue(RRhelper.ComeToMenuItem(DRIVER, "Favoritter"));
        Thread.sleep(300);
        String image_path=".//result//UpgradeTest/NewVersion//";
        String name="FavoriteSetting_"+APK_file;
        RRhelper.takeScreenshot(DRIVER, name, image_path);

        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using two different `apk`s you cannot reserve the package settings unless they are synced by the application using the deviceID you are installing it on(application end handling.) For an upgrade, usually the applications have an option of updating the app which could be done using the playstore/linking to a local server.

Also `fullReset` and `noReset` works on the package specified, if it would already be there noReset would not override the existing and fullReset would uninstall and then install the application.

More or so, it depends on your application how is the state of the flag/settings reserved, do you want a user to keep using the same settings while he is trying to force download another apk version or do you want to restore default settings in that case.

Comment: Thank you fro your respond! Yes I want the user to keep the seting while upgrading to new version of the app. Problem in test environment is that we are using hockeyapp to host the test version apk and there is a bug with hockyapp and we can not update the app with a link from to new version on hockeyapp. Could you specify more on how to "sync from application using the deviceID to" update the app? Can it be done from Appium?

Answer (score 0):

With appium server setting, either `fullreset` or `noreset` can server my purpose of testing the retaining of user setting after upgrade the app. As described in the question.  Now I found a solution, which is to install the app with `adb install -r`, which means reinstall an exisiting app, keeping its data.

This command line can be wrapped up in my JAVA test code. After installation with adb, start the session with appium without installation of the app,

```
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "package name");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "activity name");
```

Then I can see the settings are retained.